# Display an image in an object though html. JQuery

Tags: jquery, html, object, local-storage

I am displaying information taken from an object in local storage on a html page. the H2, H5 and p are all pulling through but i cannot get the image though. Any ideas? the code shows the Jquery and the html that i am using to pull the information into the page.

```
//JQuery
    function displayPageContent(object){
                if(object){
                    $('#bar-info h2').html(object.barname);
                    $('#bar-info h5').html(object.address);
                    $('#bar-info p').html(object.description);
                    $('#bar-info img src').html(object.image);

                }
            }
            displayPageContent(pageBar);



    //HTML
     <div class="content">
                <div id="bar-info">
                    <center><h2></h2></center>
                    <h5></h5>
                    <p></p>
                    <img scr="">
                </div>
```

Comment: Does `console.log(object.image)` display image info?

Comment: Yes it does ...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$('#bar-info img src').html(object.image);` would select an element named `src` and set its html.

You want to set the `img`'s `src` attribute: `$('#bar-info img').attr('src', object.image);`

Comment: This has worked thanks :)

Comment: Cool! If it worked, make sure to accept the answer to help others that come asking the same thing.

Answer (score 0):

You need to set the `<img>` src with `.attr()`. Like this:

$('img').attr('src', 'image-src');